# How to assign values to corresponding data in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

[image]I have 2 ArrayLists. The first contains 993 float values. I have added every 12 instances of these 993 float values together and stored them in another ArrayList (993/12), giving the second ArrayList a size of 83.

Here is a snippet of the second ArrayList:

`919.2, 927.9, 809.39996, 633.8, 626.8, 871.30005, 774.30005, 898.8, 789.6, 936.3, 765.4, 882.1, 681.1, 661.3, 847.9, 683.9, 985.7, 771.1, 736.6, 713.2001, 774.49994, ...`

The first of these values i.e `919.2` corresponds to the year 1930.

The second, `927.9` corresponds to the year 1931.

The third, `809.39996` corresponds to the year 1932 and so on... meaning the last 83rd value will correspond to 2012.

The ultimate aim I have is to look at these values in this second ArrayList and find the largest, printing its value AND the year that corresponds with it.
The issue is the program currently has no way of knowing these corresponding year values.

Allowed assumption: the first corresponding year value is 1930.

Currently I am able to successfully print the largest value in the ArrayList which is half the problem.
To achieve this is simply sorted the ArrayList:
`System.out.println(depthAdd.get(depthAdd.size() -1));`

What im lacking is the corresponding year. How can I do this???

Here is some code for you:

```
  public void depthValues() {
    ArrayList<Float> rValue = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    ArrayList<Float> depthAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Float> it = rValue.iterator();
    final int MAX = 12;

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        float sum = 0f;
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter <= MAX && it.hasNext()) {
          sum += it.next();
          counter++;
        }
        depthAdd.add(sum);
    }


    Collections.sort(depthAdd);
    System.out.println("Wettest year: //year needs to go here "
    + depthAdd.get(depthAdd.size() -1));




    return;

  }
```

Comment: Am I correct to assume the year is just 1930 + the index? So can't you just do year = 1930 + myList.indexOf(myNum)?

Comment: Sort the list to get the biggest element is an expensive action O(n log n), it can be done in O(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could copy the original `List` (before sorting). And then iterate again to determine matching position(s). Another option is to create a custom class to contain the year and the value, and create a custom `Comparator` on the ammount of rainfall. The first might be implemented like

```
List<Float> depthCopy = new ArrayList<>(depthAdd);
Collections.sort(depthAdd);
Float max = depthAdd.get(depthAdd.size() - 1);
for (int i = 0; i < depthCopy.size(); i++) {
    if (depthCopy.get(i).equals(max)) {
        System.out.println("Wettest year: " + (1930 + i) + " "
                + depthAdd.get(depthAdd.size() - 1));

    }
}
```

Comment: Am i putting this below the `depthAdd.add(sum);` // ref to original code posted?

If so this doesnt seem to be doing anything :( my console is still reporting just the value same as without this code.

Comment: @Abbie Replace the code you have around `Collections.sort`. And make sure you have my `println` (you should be seeing the `year` now).

Comment: hmm thought that would work cant understand why it doesnt.. still not working please see the updated post. now ive commented out my `Collections.sort` its not printing anything. the value i had or the year.

Comment: @Abbie I was missing a `get`. Edited.

Comment: I hope you dont mind me asking a further add-on question here but the value that was being returned (is correct):
`1146.440001525879`
How could I round this to 1decimal place i.e `1146.4`. Figured it would be easier to ask where someone knows whats going on here already. I did change to <Double> to try do this many different ways, however nothing works. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). I think you want "0.0" or "0.#". A decimal number doesn't have a format. See also the [Secret Robot Internet](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2999).

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the index and maximum value in separate variables:

```
float maxValue;
int maxIndex;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    float sum = 0f;
    int counter = 1;
    while (counter <= MAX && it.hasNext()) {
      sum += it.next();
      counter++;
    }
    if (sum > maxValue) {
       maxValue = sum;
       maxIndex = depthAdd.size(); // The current index
    }
    depthAdd.add(sum);
}
```

Then print the value:

```
System.out.println("The max was " + maxValue + " in " + (1930 + maxIndex));
```

Comment: what are we saying maxValue is here its unassigned, 1930? also I dont believe i could use the variable name sum again can i? if i use `sum` then the actual float number i get changes, it does print 1930 however, but now the value is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you need/want to store the value pairs you could use something like `Map<Integer, Float>` and directly reference the key value pair after sorting. Otherwise, either of the previous answers should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Float max =   depthAdd.get(0);
int index = 0;
for (int i = 1; I < r.size(); i++) 
   if (depthAdd.get(i) > max) {
      max = depthAdd.get(i);
      index = i;
   }
```

int year = 1930 + index;

And max will be the biggest value;

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a key,value pair.  That's a job for a Map, not a List.

```
Map<Integer,Float> depthAdd = new HashMap<Integer,Float>();
...
int year = 1930;
while(it.hasNext()) {
    float sum = 0f;
    int counter = 1;
    while (counter <= MAX && it.hasNext()) {
      sum += it.next();
      counter++;
    }
    depthAdd.put(year, sum);
    year++;
}
...
```